# Is it possible to make an outline around the continents in Mapbox Studio?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-android

I would like to create a map of the world like the one in this image: [image]

I am until now only familiar with Googlemaps studio, and it does not have the capacity to make a theme with outlines of the continents like this (though it is possible with a ludicrously sized file containing country outlines.) Is this possible in Mapbox studio?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Mapbox studio is far more capable than Googlemaps.

Comment: Gkad you solved it. You can edit this answer to show exactly how you solved it, to help future visitors to your question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).